# What's a non-ActiveDirectory domain?

Tags: active-directory

I'm new to Active Directory and all that stuff.

What does a non-ActiveDirectory domain mean?

I'll be more clear. There was this answer in a discussion " NetBIOS is a legacy Windows NT 4 name, only around for compatibility with non-ActiveDirectory domains"

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser LaHwF Sk, unfortunately your question is unclear, especially the phrase, "non-ActiveDirectory domains means" which does not seem to have meaning. If you could expand on what you are trying to do/learn and possibly rephrase the phrase in question we may be able to help.

Comment: i'll be more clear , there was this answer in a discussion " NetBIOS is a legacy Windows NT 4 name, only around for compatibility with non-ActiveDirectory domains"  i guess this was more helpful , thanks mate

Comment: Then that would be an NT-4 Domain (Pre-Windows 2000), which uses NETBIOS

Answer (score 3):

> there was this answer in a discussion " NetBIOS is a legacy Windows NT 4 name, only around for compatibility with non-ActiveDirectory domains"

Active Directory is the "directory service" feature **introduced in Windows 2000** and based primarily around LDAP and other Internet standards. It mainly supports centralized logon, and the AD 'domain' is a collection of user accounts & computers participating in it.

But **before the introduction of Active Directory,** Windows NT 3.x/4.x already had the same centralized logon feature – called just "NT domains" – however, the underlying protocols were different. For example, it only supported a flat list of accounts – no hierarchical OUs. (I think the original system dates to MS-DOS "LAN Manager" and related products.)

Therefore, a "non-ActiveDirectory domain" is a collection of user accounts & computers participating in the old centralized logon protocols used by Windows (3.x/9x/NT3/NT4), MS-DOS, and OS/2, but lacking Active Directory support.

This original system used NetBIOS Session Service to run all of its communications protocols – not raw TCP/IP, but NetBIOS over TCP/IP, NetBIOS over IPX, NetBIOS over Ethernet (this was still an era before TCP/IP became ubiquitous).

There *still* exist Windows networks which only support the legacy NT4 "domain logon" protocols but not Active Directory. (Some people run NT4 domain controllers on Linux using Samba 3, either because they have very weird database requirements, or just because they don't feel like migrating to this newfangled Samba 4 with Active Directory tech just yet.)

Comment: that was very helpful mate , very much obliged

Comment: @LaHwFSk Please take our short [tour] to learn what you can do with an answer that solves your problem.